# Join normalized table with active record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

There is a `customer` table with columns `id`, `name` and `email` as well as a `address` table with columns `id`, `street`, `code`, `customer_id`.

In SQL I join both by using:

```
SELECT c.id, c.name, c.email, a.street, a.code FROM customer AS c, address AS a WHERE a.customer_id = c.id;
```

In Rails I modelled:

```
class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
    self.table_name = 'address'
end
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
    self.table_name = 'customer'

    has_one :address
end
```

In the controller I tried:

- `Customer.joins(:address)` => `SELECT customer.* FROM customer INNER JOIN address ON address.customer_id = customer.id`
- `Customer.includes(:address)` => `SELECT customer.* FROM customer; SELECT address.* FROM address  WHERE address.customer_id IN (1, 2)`

However both do not return the expected result.

**How do I get the same results as defined in the first SQL Query or what is the right way to do this?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not quite the way, but I understand where you're coming from, having learned Rails after doing a lot of DB work. Run console to test these ideas. First, the Address correctly "belongs_to" the Customer. The Customer "has_one" Address. these are defined in the Model. Think of the model as a database table. The foreign keys are defined by these relationships you've specified. The join is interpreted by the relationship.

So, in console, create an address.

```
> Address.create(:street => "123 Main")
```

The output will show the new address's ID. Create a customer record, and in the address_id column, put the id of the address.

```
Customer.create(:address_id=> [ new address id ] )
```

Query the customer:

```
> customer =  Customer.find([id number])
```

Then, type

```
> customer.address
```

It should show you the address. No joins necessary (but they are happening on the server).

And, you don't need to specify the table names in the model.

Comment: Thank you! Do you know if ActiveRecord uses lazy loading and because of this it may sometimes hide properties?

Comment: You're welcome! What do you mean by hide properties? I beleive lazy loading happens with "eager" loading.